# Advise needed from experienced solr programmer to create solr index

Tags: solr, indexing, dataimporthandler

Using dataimporthandler of solr to make an jquery autocomplete for a textbox.

I want to query all products present in the table "Products". There is a foreign key to the "Features" table. A product may or may not have one or more features.

I want the product name in a field (say "Product"), and all its features associated with  it. Each product will have features in one multivalued field separated by a comma.

I want to do this to make the index smaler and thus make the searches faster.

Instead of having:

product1 -> feature1

product1 -> feature2

product1 -> feature3

product1 -> feature4

(document with two fields)

it will be:

product1 -> [ feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4 ]

This approach will make the index contain less documents. I feel it'll provide fast search results. Though, it will result in some work on the client to split the field and update the textbox.

The only drawback as I can see is that the feature field will sometimes be large with regard to Ngram.

And also what SQL query would accomplish creating the documents for this? Is there a filter that can be used to insert a comma delimiter between different features?

Comment: Do you have any sample document,schema code to share with as a starting point?

Comment: I havent really started implementing the solution yet cause i want to know first what approach is the best way and if anyone can see any drawbacks in using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand how sql falls into this to be honest but you should end up in solr with something like

```
{Document1{product:ProductName,features:{[feature1,feature2,feature3,...]}}}
```

Its informal json but this is how it could look like into solr. You would retrieve it with a query on /select handler with something like:

```
/select?q*:*&fq=product:ProductName or something of the sort.
```

Comment: Thanks! The sql is used in the dataimporthandler to create the documents from a database.